# File Path Name and User Input

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream

I am trying to have the user input the file path of a file to be read by my program. However, when I try to compile the code, it errors, with the following error: no matching function to call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(std::string&)'. The code works correctly with no errors when I directly enter the file instead of using getline or cin. I don't know what is the problem. Any suggestions?

```
int main()
{
 ifstream input_file;
 string file_name;
 cout<< "Please input file path to PostFix arithmetic expressions file\n";
 getline(cin, file_name);
 input_file.open(file_name);
 read_and_evaluate(input_file);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this example by using `string file_name="foo"`, and you can find the answer by looking up the documentation of `ifstream::open` (e.g. google "ifstream").

Comment: The error means what it says. There's no overload of `open` that is compatible with a `std::string` argument (at least until C++11).

Comment: Another hint: you might want to look up the member functions of `std::string` as well.

Comment: Thanks all! After working on this project code for 12 hrs straight, the common sense things start to elude me. Thanks again.

Comment: `file_name.c_str()` is what have used in the past - as others have said, `ifstream.open()` method doesn't accept a string as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile as C++11 in order to get an `ifstream` constructor or `open` member function that takes a `std::string` argument. With g++ use the `-std=c++11` option.

In C++03 iostream constructors only supported C strings, which you can get via `std::string::c_str()`.

Do note that regardless of C string or `std::string`, in Windows this will fail to open a file with non-ANSI characters in the path, unless you first shorten the path to DOS 8.3 path items (which are pure ASCII).